# How to refactor a class where some methods do not use passed-in dependencies?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, dependencies, refactoring

Suppose you have the following Controller class

```
class MyController
{
    /* @var Db */
    private $db;

    function __construct(DB $db){/*..*/}

    function showEntryScreen(){/*..*/}

    function showForm(){/*..*/}

    function saveData(){/*..*/}
}
```

Suppose `showEntryScreen` does *not* make use of `DB` instance.  It just shows the entry screen, without making use of any database or data facilities at all.  But the remaining methods do rely on having access to the database.

**Question:**

How do I handle `DB` injection into the `MyController` class?

For example, since `DB` is not strictly mandatory in all cases, do I instead inject `DB` via a setter method? Do I refactor `showEntryScreen` into another controller that doesn't use `DB`?

Strictly speaking, initializing `DB` is wasted when I call `showEntryScreen` method.  What is a recommended way to deal with this?  Or is it okay to overlook this until it becomes a measurable problem?

A little more detail drawing on exact code I currently have:

```
// Show the entry screen with or without Quote
$home = new MyController();

/* 
 * $id is that of the Quote
 * When $id is defined (from SESSION) Quote object is open and needs DB connections
 * otherwise, Quote is closed and we show the entry screen, no DB required
 */
if ($id)
{
    $home->setMainRepository(new MainRepository($id));
    $home->setDbRepository(new DbRepository());
    $home->setQuoteRepository(new QuoteRepository($id));
    $home->setHomeRepository(new HomeRepository($id));
}

$home->showEntryScreen();
```

In other words, I use setter methods and populate DB Repositories only when I deem they will be required.  Otherwise, I leave them all as null, for that one method and for that one use case when Quote `$id` is not defined

Comment: You can inject a closure that returns the db instance on-demand, but if `showEntryScreen` returns a static content, I wouldn't load php at all. It is way more expensive than an extra connection to the db, if you are optimising to such degree.

Comment: you could make showEntryScreen static so it can be accessed without a Controller instance

Comment: It's a code smell. Your class is doing too much. You should break out a new class for the `showEntryScreen` method and require it as a dependency in `MyController`

Comment: @Jeff, will it be okay if I have a single controller with a single method in it for this?  I am concerned if I begin to rid codebase of codesmells, I will end up with incredibly high number of disparate controller classes...

Comment: @Alex, are you talking about serving a static HTML?  In some cases I can do this but in others I still have various other logic on the pages, or other dependencies where PHP still needs to run..

Comment: What "various other logic" depends on, if not on the database? If it is 3rd party API it is already too slow to be concerned about an extra db connection.

Comment: in my case I use Zend `partial`, which is Zend Framework View Helper construct.  You pass it a file name and a map of keys => variables, and it creates HTML script for you substituting keys with values.  the key I pass in is whether or not the Sales Quote is "open" or "closed".  In that view script I have slightly different entry screen showing when Quote is open and when Quote is closed, and I have an if/then/else statement in my view script that is processed by PHP.  When quote is indeed open, I have DB defined as well and PHP is required then.  Only time it's not is when Quote is closed

Comment: I've also updated my question to show how I deal with this now.

Comment: ah, fair enough. Forgot about sessions.